# Rolify with_all_roles not working if User model has resource defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rolify

I want to get a list of say moderators from User model, it works in this case

```
u = User.new(:name => "n", :surname => "s", :email => "a@m.c", :password => "x")
u.add_role(:moderator)
u.save!
```

but if i assign a resource to User model like this, it's not listing users with role moderator

```
u = User.new(:name => "m", :surname => "b", :email => "a@m.c", :password => "x")
u.add_role(:moderator, Post.first)
u.save!
```

UPDATE

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :content
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
end
```

Comment: Could you add your Post model to question?

Comment: check this https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/55

Comment: check this issue its have some information related to your question which can give you a right direction http://www.github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/55

Comment: thanks, this is the first link which i've looked at, the author of gem says, by using User.with_any_role you can get all users having :admin role, but it fetches only users with resource not specified in roles model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `resourcify` to your Post model and other all models you want to apply roles on, as described in [readme](https://github.com/EppO/rolify#32-configure-your-resource-models).

So, your Post model should look like:

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  attr_accessible :user_id, :content
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*** EDIT ***

You can get all users with role :admin using `User.with_all_roles({:name => :admin})`

I've created a vanilla project uses rolify with same User and Post model. Change Post model and add `resourcify`, change User model and add `has_many :posts`

```
user = User.create(...)
user.add_role :admin
post = user.posts.create(...)
user2 = User.create(...)
user2.add_role(:moderator, post)
```

Seems working with these:

- User.with_all_roles({:name => :admin})
- User.with_all_roles({:name => :moderator, :resource => Post })
- User.with_all_roles({:name => :moderator, :resource => Post.first })

Comment: thanks, please read carefully the title of question, there's nothing to do with post model ))))\